# JavaScript Regular expressions check if a certaine number of special characters in a string

Tags: javascript, regex

```
Olivier Bonnard | 9060 rue Saint-Hubert | 180
```

I want to determine if a string includes exactly two "|", and get the value after the second "|" (here, like 180).

I tried `/[|]{2}/`, but didn't work.

Comment: Do you wanna achieve this result using `regex` only? I mean you can can easily achieve this using string manipulation.

Comment: Of course it is not limited to methods, it's just that I was thinking of using regular expressions to determine if there are and only two special symbols ”｜“ in the string. After this rule is met, then the value after the last | of the string is taken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may also try this regex:

```
^(?:[^|]*\|){2}\s*([^|]*?)\s*$
```

- `^` start of the string
- `^(?:[^|]*\|){2}` anything that not made by `|` that followed by a `|`, match 2 of them.
- `\s*([^|]*?)\s*` after two `|`s, get everything that not a `|` and get rid of the whitespaces on both ends. Capture it in group 1.
- `$` end of the string

---

According to your description, if the input has not exactly two `|`s, it always returns `undefined`.

```js
function extract(text) {
  return /^(?:[^|]*\|){2}\s*([^|]*?)\s*$/[Symbol.match](text)?.[1];
}

// undefined
console.log(extract('Olivier Bonnard | 180'));

// 180
console.log(extract('Olivier Bonnard | 9060 rue Saint-Hubert | 180'));

// undefined
console.log(extract('Olivier Bonnard | 9060 rue Saint-Hubert | 180 | #23'));
```

See the test result [here](https://regex101.com/r/mRIByS/1/)

Answer (score 0):

```js
const myString = 'Olivier Bonnard | 9060 rue Saint-Hubert | 180';
const m = myString.match(/[^\|]*\|[^\|]*\|(.*)/);
console.log(m[1].trim());
```

I've added the `.trim()` for good measure, because I assume you don't want the space before the number, right?

Comment: *I want to determine if a string includes exactly two "|"*, but this regex doesn't ensure that.

Comment: yan, glad it works. Please don't forget to upvote and accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

It also work with a less complex regex and you can add a bool statement :

```
const myString = 'Olivier Bonnard | 9060 rue Saint-Hubert | 180';
const m =  /\|.*\|/.test(myString) ? (myString.match(/\|.*\|(.+)/))[1].trim() : false ;
console.log(m); // print false if the condition is not fulfilled
```